# How to fix navigation route from protected route to login page?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm working on a React application where I have public and private routes. When a user tries to access a protected route without being logged in, they are correctly redirected to the login page. However, I've noticed that if the user clicks the browser's back button after being redirected to the login page, they get stuck on the login page. How can I prevent this issue and ensure that users can go to the previous url before the protected routes?

For example I i am on the public url (/public-url1) and i tried to go to private url (/private-url1) then i will be automatically move to /login. Now if i click back I will stay at login (because i will reach to private-url1 and login check happens which will again redirect me to login).

PrivateRoutes.js

```
const PrivateRoutes = () => {

   const [loggedIn,setLoggedIn] = useState(false);
   
   
   useEffect(() => {
     if(isLoggedIn()){
        setLoggedIn(true);
     }
     else{
      // make API call and use refresh token to refresh access token
      // set loggedIn to true/false
     }
      
   },[])

   if(loading) return <Loading/>;
   return loggedIn ? <Outlet/>: <Navigate to='/login/' />
}
```

App.js

```
export const routes = [
    {
      path: "/",
      element: <Outlet/>,
      children: [
         // some public url

         {
            path: "/private-url/",
            element: <PrivateRoutes/>,
            children: [
              {
                path: "",
                element: <PrivateHome/>
              },
              // some more private routes
            ]
         }
      ]
    }

]


const App = () => {
  return useRoutes(routes);
};

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of PUSHing the navigation to `"/login"` you should redirect to `"/login"` using a REPLACE navigation action. Additionally, the log-in component should redirect back to the original route the user was trying to access once a user has successfully authenticated. This logic maintains the history stack such that any back navigation avoids being able to navigate back to the login page.

```
import { Outlet, useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';

const PrivateRoutes = () => {
  const location = useLocation();

  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [loggedIn, setLoggedIn] = useState(false);
   
  useEffect(() => {
    if (isLoggedIn()) {
      setLoggedIn(true);
      setLoading(false);
    } else {
      // make API call and use refresh token to refresh access token
      // set loggedIn to true/false
    } 
  }, []);

  if (loading) return <Loading/>;

  return loggedIn
    ? <Outlet/>
    : (
      <Navigate
        to="/login"
        replace                    // <-- redirect
        state={{ from: location }} // <-- current location
      />
    );
};
```

```
const Login = () => {
  const { state } = useLocation();
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  ...

  const loginHandler = () => {
    ... auth logic ...

    const from = location.state?.from ?? "/";
    navigate(
      from,             // <-- original location, or home
      { replace: true } // <-- redirect
    );
  };

  ...
};
```

Comment: Thank you. I added `replace:true` in Navigate inside PrivateRoutes.js and it started working. I dont understand your `loginHandler`. when its going to trigger ?

Comment: @Anonymous Welcome, glad to help. Did this answer address/resolve the question/issue you had?

Comment: @Anonymous The `loginHandler` is just a callback function, e.g. a user clicks a "Log In" button or submits a form, etc. Does it make sense now?